# Select2 disable/enable specific option

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-select2

I have a list which is of type select2.

```
<select id="list" class="form-control select2 select2-hidden-accessible" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<optgroup label="Types">
<option value="None">None</option>
<option value="1">One</option>
<option value="2">Two</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I want to disable option which is having **value=1**
so I did like this

```
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").prop('disabled',true);
   Result:// <option value="1" disabled>One</option>
```

It is working fine;but if i want to re-enable disabled option i tried below codes but still the select2 option is disabled.

```
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").prop('disabled',false);
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").removeProp('disabled');
  Result://   <option value="1">One</option>
```

but strange is disabled property of the option is removed. but the select2 option remains disabled.

Not getting how to resolve this. Need help.

Update: If I check DOM of select2 it is having this property even after removing disabled.

```
<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-template-type-list-result-4qd3-merge" role="treeitem" aria-disabled="true">One</li>
```

if i make **aria-disabled="false"** it will enable. not able to get what is the cause.

Comment: Have you tried calling `.select2(…)` on the element again after changing the disabled attribute?

Comment: $("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").prop('disabled',false);
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").removeProp('disabled');
$("#list").select2();

Comment: @CBroe the issue with the re-enable of option. disable function working properly. I tried calling select2(). it is working properly. But i am not able to get what is the issue in select2?

Comment: Works fine for me by simply calling `.select2` again after changing the `disabled` state of an option: http://jsfiddle.net/xoxd2u15/

Comment: @CBroe Invoking select2 again works.Thanks. But for normal select no need to invoke any function.what could be the issue?

Comment: Of course there is no need to invoke anything else for a “normal” select field, because that is a default HTML element that the browser renders directly. But select2 _replaces_ that select field with custom HTML elements (and hides the original) – and apparently it does not “watch” the options of that original select element for changes in their disabled state constanstly after invocation, and so you have to call it once more after changing the state, so that it reads the _current_ attribute values from the original element’s options …

Comment: Ok, I added this as an answer.

Comment: Has this been fixed in select2 v4.0 ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Probably easiest way to achieve this, would be calling `.select2(…)` on the element again after changing the disabled attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/xoxd2u15/

Since select2 *replaces* the original select field with custom HTML elements (and hides the original), and apparently does not “watch” the options of that original select element for changes in their disabled state constantly after invocation, you have to call it once more after changing the state, so that it reads the current attribute values from the original element’s options.

Comment: This is [a known bug](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3347) in Select2 4.0.0. The `disabled` property is cached, but the `selected` (and other properties) are not.

Comment: Hey @Kevin, thanks for the info. Glad to see you’re working on fixing this for future versions.

Comment: This has been fixed: https://github.com/select2/select2/commit/bd7ac9df03b008f03bb15c66fcab4682589bfc2a

Comment: As mentioned by Joel, that commit fixes select2 not obeying option disabled state.  Upgrading to version 5.0.13 fixed it for me so that $('option').attr('disabled') and $('option').removeAttr('disabled') work as expected without having to reload select2 on the select.

Answer (score 4):

For Disable Try this:

```
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").attr('disabled','disabled');
```

To remove Disable Try this:

```
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: I did the same. It is still disabled. Please check my question once.

Answer (score 2):

This will work if u do not want to unbind and bind the select option

```
$('#list option[value="1"]').data().data.disabled = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#list").find(':selected').attr('disabled','disabled');
$("#list").trigger('change');
```

## See Official Doc

https://select2.org/programmatic-control/retrieving-selections

Comment: Please provide a bit more context to your answer/explain it a bit, e.g.: What has changed since the questions was asked, the accepted answer given?

Comment: With versionn 4.03, this is working as expected. Using jQuery, use the find to query select the desired option. You can "removeAttr" to remove the disabled attribute. I would suggest change the given url to https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Answer (score 1):

If you are plan to disable and enable select options with select2 class dynamically, you can use below as reference.

I have two select tags(with ids xaxis and yaxis) with same list of options and i want user not to select same option for this select tag.

```
function checkfieldvalue(value,select_id)
{   
  /* enable all options first */
  $('#xaxis option').prop('disabled',false); 
  $('#yaxis option').prop('disabled',false);
  if(select_id==0){
    $('#xaxis option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('disabled',true);      
  }else{
    $('#yaxis option[value="'+value+'"]').prop('disabled',true);      
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some strange instances when you need to remove both the prop (node property) and the attr (Document HTML Attribute). They are in fact not one in the same though jQuery tends to treat them that way.

So you would need to do

```
$("#list>optgroup>option[value='1']").removeAttr('disabled').removeProp('disabled');
```

This way it both removes the node property and the dom attribute.

That said you likely need to update the select2 instance which nobody here mentioned the right solution for.

```
$('#list').trigger('change.select2');
```

.trigger('change') would also work but has some side effects if other functionality is hooked into the change event. Further you can't use it inside an already hooked on('change') function.

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code will disable all the options.

```
$('#list  option').prop('disabled',true);
```

This line will enable only option that is having value 1.

```
$('#list option[value="1"]').prop('disabled',false);

$('#list').select2();
```

Above is more simplified answer.